# Batch export in SAS for spk file

Tags: batch-file, sas

I need to export/import my spk file via windows Batch script.

For which I have been referring [this document](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=bisag&docsetTarget=n008xsxs34mvcwn1qrgcmugpzu6i.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

But this document does not mention how to save the file (I mean with which extension `.bat` or `.sas`)

My command:

```
ExportPackage -profile "SAS_MW_TEST" -package "F:\mypath\Package4.spk" -objects "/_Applications/_05_MW/_01_SAS_MW/_20_Processes/savedesk(Folder)" -subprop -types "Condition,BusinessRuleFlow,ExternalFile,Cube,SearchFolder,Table,GeneratedTransform,OLAPSchema,InformationMap.OLAP,Measure,Column,Job.CubeBuild,Action,Library,MiningResults,DeployedJob,CalculatedMeasure,Hierarchy,InformationMap.Relational,RootFolder,Prompt,Document,ConditionActionSet,DecisionLogic,Dimension,Note,StoredProcess,PromptGroup,Job,OrchestrationJob,MessageQueue,Service.SoapGenerated,Level,SharedDimension,DeployedFlow"
```

Comment: You want save the code , which do export?

Answer (score 0):

`ExportPackage` is an executable program that you can run out of a batch file.

Use Notepad or any other text editor (which includes any SAS code editor), place the ExportPackage program command in the editor and use the File/Save As feature to save the file as something like `myPackageExporter.bat`

If the items in the package are say stored processes whose metadata says the source code is in an file system folder (aka source code repository), you will probably also want to zip up the folder.

Comment: I actually tried using the .bat file; but it gives the error saying Invalid command. I guess there would be some command in windows to invoke this ExportPackage command

Comment: `ExportPackage` is found under your SAS Home installation folder.  Try the full path `C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASPlatformObjectFramework\9.4\ExportPackage.exe`

Answer (score 0):

This macro can help you prepare the batch script, ready for export:  https://core.sasjs.io/mm__spkexport_8sas.html